# Many to Many relationship Users and Companies set default record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, default

What is the best way to setup a default company relationship for a user?

> Options:
>
> 1. Set a default boolean field on the many to many Roles table
> 2. Add a default_company field on the User table

If 1, is there a good method to making sure there is only one default company per user? Any built in methods, etc?  Any other better ideas?

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :companies, :through => :roles
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
end
```

Comment: add a method inside user model and call this with before_save

Comment: @devanand before_save does not really address which way is the better way, pros and cons of each option, or advice on another method for storing and changing the default.  The question again,is should default field be stored in the roles model or user model.  pros, cons?

Comment: thats right. sorry i've misunderstood the topic. i would use a flag in the role relation. this allows you to use the same mechanism for company and default company. otherwise another interesting approach would be a STI for a default company based on role model

Comment: @devanand I am adding a flag in the role relation, what code would use use in the before_save to set the default?

Comment: Created a new related, but different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127986/before-save-change-default-value-for-many-to-many  to address the before_save issue.