# Before_save = Change default value for many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, before-save

Can someone help me figure out what code I should put in my change_default method?

I would like to be able to do something like this...

```
user = User.find(1)
user.companies.first.default!
or 
user.companies.find_by_company_id(2).default!
```

My code:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base 
  before_save :change_default

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  def change_default
    #update default field for to false for current scope
    #Update current record default field to true

    #this is what I currently have, but it's not setting my defaults to false
    if self.default == true
     roles = Roles.where( :user_id => self.user_id) 
     roles.update_all(:default => false)
    end
  end

  def default!
    self.default=true
    self.save
  end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :companies, :through => :roles
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
end
```

Code run:

```
pry(main)> a.roles.last.default!

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
SCOPING
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "roles" SET "default" = 'f' WHERE "roles"."user_id" = 1
   (2.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true

[5] pry(main)> a.roles

=> [#<Role id: 1, company_id: 1, name: nil, view_document: nil, edit_document: nil, upload_document: nil, delete_document: nil, review_document: nil, company_info: nil, company_clients: nil, company_users: nil, company_admin: nil, created_at: "2014-08-04 20:10:23", updated_at: "2014-08-04 22:29:40", user_id: 1, default: true>,

    #<Role id: 2, company_id: 2, name: nil, view_document: nil, edit_document: nil, upload_document: nil, delete_document: nil, review_document: nil, company_info: nil, company_clients: nil, company_users: nil, company_admin: nil, created_at: "2014-08-04 20:11:10", updated_at: "2014-08-04 20:11:10", user_id: 1, default: nil>,

    #<Role id: 3, company_id: 3, name: nil, view_document: nil, edit_document: nil, upload_document: nil, delete_document: nil, review_document: nil, company_info: nil, company_clients: nil, company_users: nil, company_admin: nil, created_at: "2014-08-04 20:11:14", updated_at: "2014-08-04 22:29:16", user_id: 1, default: true>]
```

As you can see the update ran, but the default values are not set to false.  If you have any recommendations or things I can check, please let me know.

Comment: Though I'm not 100% sure what exactly you would like done, it looks like your second `if` block is missing an `end`. Unless it's just me, please comment or edit to make what exactly you're having difficulty with more clear.

Comment: sorry, that was a paste error. pasted code is corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to exclude the current record that is being modified.  Added the where.not clause

```
  def change_default
    if self.default_changed? && self.default == true
      roles = Role.where( :user_id => self.user_id)
      roles = roles.where.not(:id => self.id)
      roles.update_all(:default => false)  
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why that must be true, do you?

Comment: Not sure, but it works now.  Maybe some type of conflict with updating a record being updated. Really not sure. thank you for the help

Comment: I wonder if `update_all` uses `save`. Maybe there was some recursion causing a timeout or something.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the example you never call `save` on the roles. Therefore, your `before_save :change_default` is not being executed. Perhaps adding `role.save` in `def default!` would at least have the `before_save` be executed because I'm not sure that your current console test is actually running the `change_default` method.

If I am wrong and it actually is running, then I'm not sure why your block would not set the `default` value to false.

Comment: Have self.save in Def default... had an update to correct that. you must of posted before the update. any other ideas would be much appreciated.